# How can I Count in multiple table?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

I have some problem to get the ID which use on another table row. I have three tables. One is category, articles, video. In articles and video there is a column which have category ID. This is the example:

Table Categories :

```
id | category_name
------------------
1  | News
2  | Sports
3  | Art
4  | Horror
```

Table Articles :

```
id | category_id | title
----------------------------------
1  | 1           | title content 1
2  | 1           | title content 2
3  | 3           | title content 3
4  | 3           | title content 4
5  | 2           | title content 5
```

Table Video :

```
id | category_id | video_title
------------------------------
1  | 1           | video title 1
2  | 2           | video title 2
3  | 3           | video title 3
```

I want to get each category ID already use what time in two other databases. Like this :

```
Category ID 1 is use 3 times
Category ID 2 is use 2 times
Category ID 3 is use 3 times
Category ID 4 is use 0 times
```

What query do I need to use so I can get all data like that ? Please anyone knows could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those a separate tables, not databases.

Comment: @BenM Yes, I mean separate table in same database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to `UNION ALL` `articles` table  and `video` table be a subquery, then use `Outer join` and `COUNT` function.

```
SELECT Concat('Category ID  ', c.id, ' is use ', Count(t.category_id ), ' times') 
FROM   categories c 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT category_id 
                  FROM   articles 
                  UNION ALL 
                  SELECT category_id 
                  FROM   video) t 
              ON c.id = t.category_id 
GROUP  BY c.id
```

SQLFIDDLE:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92cbd0e/12

**[Results]**:

```
| Concat('Category ID  ', t.id, ' is use ', t.cnt, ' times') |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
|                              Category ID  1 is use 3 times |
|                              Category ID  2 is use 2 times |
|                              Category ID  3 is use 3 times |
|                              Category ID  4 is use 0 times |
```

**NOTE**

- `COUNT` function does not count numbers if the column value encounters `null`

For example Here is a sample script.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   col int
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1);

SELECT COUNT(col) FROM  t;  -- RESULT  = 1

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  t;  --RESULT = 2
```

sample sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2bba7/2

Comment: I tried that and works perfectly but I didn't got 0 values if the category ID is not use. How could to do that ?

Comment: add coalesce like count(coalesce(t.category_id, 0)

Comment: I add some note wish can help you.

Comment: @Gaj why I got value 1 from un-use category ? My all category show up but if the category ID never use it's give me value 1

Comment: I don't have `NULL` value in this case.

Comment: @Antonio You dont have null value but if you do Left outer join then it will null for category 4 because category_id 4 not available in Articles and video table

Comment: @Gaj So, what I should do now so I could get 0 value if the category is never use ?

Comment: Try this

SELECT Concat('Category ID  ', c.id, ' is use ', Count(coalesce(t.category_id,0)), ' times') 
FROM   categories c 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT category_id 
                  FROM   articles 
                  UNION ALL 
                  SELECT category_id 
                  FROM   video) t 
              ON c.id = t.category_id 
GROUP  BY c.id

Comment: @Antonio sorry i missed that. I have corrected this query. 
instead of count you use sum 
sum(case when t.category_id is null then 0 else 1 end)

Comment: @Gaj Could you give me the query you've corrected please. Thanks.

Comment: @Gaj sorry no need for that. I already tried to change count with sum and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, for example, this query:

```
Select category_id, count(1) - 1
  From (
    Select category_id From video
    Union All Select category_id From articles
    Union All Select id From Categories)
  Group By category_id
```

Comment: Your query wont return category 4

Comment: dont try to add master table in the union. This is wrong approach

Comment: You unnecessarily add the categories table in union and then subtract 1